# what are approaches to work with settings

Tags: c

What are some approaches to work with custom setting files in C.

For example, I plan to do it like this.
Say I have file `settings.ext` and I want to store 3 string parameters
inside. What I will do is: assuming my string parameters are at most
32 bytes length, I will assume that my parameters inside file are stored
like this (in binary mode):

```
32 byte        32 byte        32 byte
---------------------------------------------
| 1 param     || 2 param     || 3 param     |
```

Then if I want second string parameter, I will read 32 bytes starting from index: 32,
again in binary mode.

I think I will have separate file for string parameters and separate
file for int parameters (I will work with int parameters in similar manner).

Does this sound reasonable?

ps. I am programming on some embedded device

Comment: My tip is to *not* have binary files for settings. Use a simple text format, like `key1 = value1` on separate lines. Just because strings will not be longer than 32 characters (or 31 if you store the terminator too) *just now*, think about what will happen if you want longer in the future.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I see what you mean. But it is unlikely I will need longer ones in the future. Plus I am more comfortable with binary files reading writing. And also I have some SDK which I am not sure even if it has read write in text mode.... if that's the only concern I think I will stick with binary approach

Comment: That's a very bad platform description. It seems like you've already made up your mind to do what you suggest, and there is nothing wrong with your approach, so whatever works for you. It's not the most efficient way to do what you want though.

Comment: @jbr: Hi jbr thanks, it's not that I made up my mind, but if my approach will work I think I am fine with it. Plus like I said I am not sure if read and write in text mode are supported by this SDK. thanks for your comments anyway

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a binary file for saving settings, of the top of my head there are the following reasons not to:

1. It's not very portable because of endianness etc.
2. It's not not very easy to extend, you might not need any extra config parameters right now, but you might do later.
3. It's hard to edit and read from other programs, it's nice to be able to install and configure your software with scripts.

Instead I'd use a plain text config file, and something like [libconfig](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/), there is no reason to reinvent the wheel, especially if make it worse ;-)

Comment: I don't need portability with this app. Why is it problematic to extend? Problem is if length of individual parameter changes (as J Pileborg mentioned) but even I doubt that will happen with my case.

Comment: If you really only need three strings to configure, then pass them in as parameters instead. Otherwise it is still easier to use libconfig, as software tends to live longer life than the developer expects, so you might as well make good choices from the beginning.

Comment: What do you mean to pass them as parameters ? I am programming on some device, and it is not that reasonable for me now to "bother" with installing some libraries on that embedded device. Indeed I will just have probably couple of string parameters and ints maybe(and I described how I'd like to store them)

Comment: Fair enough, then please update your question to reflect your platform, it will improve relevance of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of standard library functions which make parsing simple tag/value configuration files easy.  Read about strtok and atoi/atof, and you might find that a simple configuration file like this easy to parse.  You can comingle string and numeric values in your configuration, and support longer strings.

```
name1=value1
name2=value2
name3=value3
...
```

This offers the benefits that it is both easily read/edited by humans, and parsed by a fairly simple configuration parser.  And passing a filename to read makes this fairly self-contained.

```
int
cfgparse(char *cfgname)
{
    FILE* cfgfh;
    if(!cfgname) return -1;
    if( !(cfgfh=fopen(cfgname,"r")) ) {
        printf("error: cannot open %s\n",cfgname);
        return -2;
    }
    char buffer[256]; //pick an acceptable max size
    while( fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),cfgfh) )
    {
        //check for comments, empty lines
        char* tag = strtok(buffer,"=");
        char* val = strtok(NULL,";\n");
        //strip leading/trailing whitespace, handle empty lines, 
        //do something with tag, value here
        Cfgadd(tag,value);
    }
}
```

You can implement a simple configuration store in an array.  A list would be dynamic, and a tree or hash would improve performance.

```
#define MaxKeyLen (200)
#define MaxValLen (200)
typedef struct
{
    char* key; //a array would work here
    char* value; //a union would allow string, int, and float
} ConfigObj;
#define CONFIGMAX (200)
const int ConfigMax=CONFIGMAX;
typedef struct
{
    ConfigObj tab[CONFIGMAX]; //or make this a pointer or a list
    int NextAvail;
} ConfigStoreObj;
ConfigStoreObj  cfg; //or make this a pointer or a list

static int ConfigFind(ConfigStoreObj* cfg, char* key)
{
    int n;
    for( n=0; (n<cfg->NextAvail) && (cfg->tab[n].key); n++ )
    {
        if( strcmp(cfg->tab[n].key,key)==0 ) //found it
        {
            return n;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
const char* ConfigGet(ConfigStoreObj* cfg, char* key)
{
    int n = ConfigFind(cfg,key);
    if( n<0 ) return NULL; //or ""?
    return cfg->tab[n].value;
}
int ConfigSet(ConfigStoreObj* cfg, char* key, char* value)
{
    char* newvalue;
    int n=ConfigFind(cfg,key);
    if( n<0 ) return -1; //error
printf("dup(%s)\n",value); fflush(stdout);
    if( !(newvalue = strndup(value,MaxValLen)) ) {
        printf("error, cannot store %s:%s\n",key,value);
        return -3;
    }
    {
    if(cfg->tab[n].value) free(cfg->tab[n].value);
    cfg->tab[n].value = newvalue;
    }
    //return cfg->tab[n].value;
    return n;
}
int ConfigAdd(ConfigStoreObj* cfg, char*key, char*value)
{
    char *newkey=NULL, *newvalue=NULL;
    int n = ConfigFind(cfg,key);
    if( n<0 )
    {
        if( n<ConfigMax )
        {
            n = cfg->NextAvail++;
printf("dup(%s)\n",key); fflush(stdout);
            if( !(newkey = strndup(key,MaxKeyLen)) ) {
                printf("error, cannot store %s:%s\n",key,value);
                return -3;
            }
        }
        else return -1;
    }
printf("dup(%s)\n",value); fflush(stdout);
    if( !(newvalue = strndup(value,MaxValLen)) ) {
        printf("error, cannot store %s:%s\n",key,value);
        if(newkey) free(newkey);
        return -3;
    }
    {
    if(cfg->tab[n].value) free(cfg->tab[n].value);
    cfg->tab[n].value = newvalue;
    }
    //return cfg->tab[n].value;
    return n;
}
```

You may also want,

```
ConfigStoreObj* ConfigStoreNew(int size);
char* ConfigDel(ConfigStoreObj* cfg, char*key);
int ConfigPrint(ConfigStoreObj* cfg);
```

Opening a config file for reading is fairly easy, as shown above.  And here is a

```
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
//...
char configname[200];
strcpy(configname,"yourconfigfilename.cfg");
cfgparse(configname); //of course, you need a ConfigStoreObj ...
//...
}
```

And there are libraries that make even complex configuration easy.

Comment: I didn't mention but I am programming on some device which has SDK - and I am not sure it has read write operations in text mode. So if there's nothing major wrong with approach I mentioned, I think I better stick to that

Comment: In a restricted environment like you describe, your approach is reasonable.  I worked on a system where we configured everything using structs we read/wrote from another system.  We had a program to build the configuration struct, and then write it (comingled text and binary), and the receiving system simply read the file into memory.  Both systems were big-endian so no byte-order issues.

Comment: I see it is interesting indeed when your configuration must be read by other system - and you wrote the settings as a struct, then endiannes issues may apply as well as struct padding etc. right? But in my case like I said indeed it is restricted environment, and also I might not need to send this setting file to another system

Comment: Yes, struct padding was an issue we had to be careful about, and we defined our numeric format as big-endian (network byte order).

Comment: Actually I discovered now as an alternative I might have to create Exactly the kind of Configuration file that you described above. Could you elaborate more about that in your answer (then I would accept it). I am more or less new to C, and don't know how to read (multiple line) files which are in text mode. (I can handle binary mode though).